# finding string in each line using grep

Tags: unix, grep, cut

I want to find values from FILE_B to **8th-17th digit** only of FILE_A.

FILE_B contains:

```
 $cat FILE_B
 9237770
 63943100
 6393390990
```

FILE_A contains

```
 $cat FILE_A
 50000092280794230000092384245540
 50000092280938880000009237770528
 50000092377704630000009154893441
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE

```
  50000092377704630000009154893441
```

since 8th-17th (9237770463) digit contains **9237770** (which is in FILE_B)

**I have a script but doesn't give me the exact output.**

```
 $cut -c 8-17 FILE_A | grep -f FILE_B
```

output:

```
 9237770
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command:

```
cut -c 8-17 FILE_A |
   grep -nf FILE_B |
     cut -d: -f1 |
       awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};FNR in a' - FILE_A
```

- add `-n` option to `grep` to print line number (suggest `fgrep`)
- then `cut` these numbers
- use `awk` to print these lines

Answer (score 0):

If you want to basically extrapolate on what you've done already, you could use `sed` to pre-process FILE_B to make it into a list of real regular expressions:

For example:

```
sed 's/.*/^.\{6\}&.*$/' FILE_B
```

Produces

```
^.{6}9237770.*$
^.{6}63943100.*$
^.{6}6393390990.*$
```

And you can use it like so:

```
egrep -f <(sed 's/.*/^.\{6\}&.*$/' FILE_B) FILE_A
```

The downsides of this approach are:

1. It does a complete pass on `FILE_B` before running `grep`
2. `grep -f` is a pretty slow operation, so if `FILE_A` or `FILE_B` is really big, this will be slow

You can mitigate Issue 1 by saving the output of the `sed` operation to a temporary file, thereby saving the first pass on `FILE_B`. You can mitigate Issue 2 by joining all of the lines in FILE_B, separating each line with a `|`, and running it as a single massive `grep`.